# Replace multiple file name inside folder in Windows Batch. The code must be in one line only

Tags: windows, batch-file, rename

I got difficulties in replacing multiple file names. 
The scenario would be :

```
[Before]
C:¥data¥
    -HOSTNAME1_20170921_5555.zip
    -HOSTNAME2_20170921_5555.zip
    -HOSTNAME3_20170921_5555.zip

[After]
C:¥data¥
    -HOSTNAME1_20170908_5555.zip
    -HOSTNAME2_20170908_5555.zip
    -HOSTNAME3_20170908_5555.zip
```

I tried the below command but not getting satisfied result.

```
RENAME C:¥data¥*20170921_5555.zip *20170908_5555.zip
```

Unfortunately the result was:

```
C:¥data¥
    -HOSTNAME1_20170920170908_5555.zip
    -HOSTNAME2_20170920170908_5555.zip
    -HOSTNAME3_20170920170908_5555.zip
```

Anyone can solve the problem?
and tell me why the above code was not working as expected.

Comment: For a single line, you would rather use powershell, which comes standard on your windows system.

Answer (score 0):

You specifically require a single line, so here is a powershell version.

```
get-childitem *20170921_5555.zip | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace("20170921_5555", "20170908_5555") }
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. But unfortunately my environment could not run the powershell. Is there any possibility to change the code to a simple windows batch code?

Comment: Not a single line as you requested. else run the same code in a batch but put call powershell before it.

Comment: I tried to call the powershell, but got no response from the system. Mine is Windows Server 2003.

Comment: pure batch is possible, but you want a single line which is not possible.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the single line code is very difficult. 
I wonder why this code doesn't work as expected >_<
`RENAME C:¥data¥*20170921_5555.zip *20170908_5555.zip`

Comment: @fahmifahim It will not work, why do you need single line code? that code does not have the intelligence to do the rename because you are not telling it to do what you think you are telling it to do.

Answer (score 0):

- Use a `for` to iterate the files with the wrong date
- a 2nd stacked `for /f` to split the name at the `_` and
- rename replacing the 2nd element with the proper date

With one single cmd line:

```
> @for %A in (*_20170921_*.zip) do @for /f "tokens=1,2* delims=_" %B in ("%A") do @echo ren "%A" "%B_20170908_%D"
ren "¥data¥-HOSTNAME1_20170921_5555.zip" "¥data¥-HOSTNAME1_20170908_5555.zip"
ren "¥data¥-HOSTNAME2_20170921_5555.zip" "¥data¥-HOSTNAME2_20170908_5555.zip"
ren "¥data¥-HOSTNAME3_20170921_5555.zip" "¥data¥-HOSTNAME3_20170908_5555.zip"
```

If the output looks OK remove the echo in front  of the ren command.
If used in a batch file the percent signs have to be doubled `%%`

BTW you could also use this Powershell script from batch:

```
powershell -NoP -C "gci '*_20170921_*.zip'|rni -NewName {$_.Name -replace '_20170921_','_20170908_'} -WhatIf
```

If the output looks OK, remove the trailing `-WhatIf`